# ASP.NET Core environment issue

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, environment-variables

I have a question regarding `Environment` variable, my `ASP.NET Core` application is returning `Staging;Development` as environment, where it is supposed to return only `Staging`.

It is fine in development environment though, but in a staging environment, it is returning both. The same case in the Prod as well it is returning `Prod;Development`.

What would be causing this issue? Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: forgot to mention local is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check you project setting< maybe there is hardcoded env. variable.
Your Project -> Properties -> Debug. Check which data situated in the Environment variables.

Also check: 
My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables

Answer (score 0):

If an environment variable is set in both the `web.config` file and at the `system level` in Windows, the value from the web.config file becomes appended to the system environment variable value. (example: Staging;Development)

Hence, in order to resolve the mentioned issue, specify the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable either in the `web.config` file or at the `system level` in Windows.

Note: This is a known [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6140)